# how to get latitude longitude from function and send it to new google.maps.LatLng( latitude ,longitude ) javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using this script to get latitude longitude from an address,

```
var latitude="";
var longitude ="";


function codeAddress(address) {

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {


    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    //  myAfterFunction();
    //  console.log(this.latitude);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude );
```

my problem is i cant get the latitude and longitude values from this function, i tried using  another function

```
function myAfterFunction(){
  console.log(latitude);
}
```

so my question is how to get latitude and longitude from my function? thank you

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: when  i  write console.log(latitude);
console.log(longitude); out of the function  ,  it said   undefined undefined

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title (I could be wrong, you should clearly indicate what your code does in the question), it sounds like you are successfully getting the latitude and longitude, but then failing to send it to the map.

The issue likely lies in the fact:

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you
>   need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the
>   request. This callback method processes the result(s). Note that the
>   geocoder may return more than one result. ([API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding))

The asynchronous nature of this means that while your call back function (`function(results, status) {...})`) is waiting on a response, you're also executing this line:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude );
```

But, of course, latitude and longitude have not yet been defined as we have no response yet.

To see this in action explicitly, replace the code defining `center` with an `alert()` or `console.log()`, and place another in the call back function and see what triggers first:

```
function codeAddress(address) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    console.log("Response recieved");
    }
  });

}
console.log("Tried to use response");
```

The simplest solution might be to place the code that requires this specific longitude and latitude inside the callback function, so that it doesn't execute until you have a response and by extension a latitude and longitude.

Comment: thank you for your response ,but even if i placed  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude ) in my function , i will need this center values later , because i have long script

Comment: If you want to use those variables (longitude and latitude), you must use it within the call back function unless you have a method to determine when the call back is completed (perhaps a function that checks every second to see if those variables are defined), but it should be fairly easy to put all of your long script into a function and call that function from within the callback function (essentially a visually different way of putting all your code that needs the latitude and longitude in the call back function).